# CSS Margin Negative without Moving Parent Container

Tags: css, overlay, margin, layer

I am trying to get on this page (http://musicaladvocacy.org/) the area where it says "Home" (The White Container in the grey gradient) to go ~60 px up, but as you can see it does that as well as moves the parent container up.  I just want the white box to move up NOT the whole thing.  So it should look like this: http://musicaladvocacy.org/index-margin.jpg

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: For a little more on negative positioning, check out this article: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can apply `position:relative; top:-60px;` on the element you need to shift up.

```
#el {
   position:relative;
   top:-60px;
   z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: +1 Actually... I think that pretty much is ideal.  Negative margins don't break the flow of the page, so trying to use them will always push other elements around.  This sort of layout scenario is exactly what relative positioning is good for.

Comment: Wow, we really learn everyday, had no idea you could use top property on relative element!

Comment: In my case, replacing "margin-top" with "top" worked until I saw that "top" added a margin to bottom. So, sometimes, using top you will fix one problem and get another one.

Comment: Be aware that this method does move the element, but the original space it had occupied remains, leaving behind a gap you may not want. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 18):

You could also add 1px padding to the top of the parent, and continue using negative margins.

```
.width { padding-top: 1px; }
.content { margin-top: -60px; }
```

This works because margins that are immediately up against one another combine into a single margin.

Comment: How does the top padding make the margins collapse, again?

Comment: If the padding is 0, then the margins are immediately adjacent. Immediately adjacent margins collapse. If the padding is at least 1px, then the parent margin and the child margin are separated, and they don't collapse.

Comment: +100 if i could. Spent an hour messing with relative positioning. Finally gave up, started to write a question, and this one popped up in the 'Questions that may already have your answer' box. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching for is the css properties "position" and "top".

```
#div-1 {
  position:relative;
  top:-60px;
}
```

See step 2 on [this guide](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/). Many other websites have more information about this properties too.