# Can't understand negative margin's way of work

Tags: html, css, margin

Please look at following html...

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.mydiv1 {
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="mydiv1">div1</div>
</div>
```

`.mydiv1` was pulled left as `10px` and through out it's parent's left border.
But nothing happens on its top.
Why did it work differently?

Comment: Actually it does work. There must be something else. Can you show us a complete exemple ?

Comment: It doesn't work differently. See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/w5Ldufcj/

Comment: @gerard your example is not the same as the OP. without changing the original code, margin-top seems to not do anything. seems like a good question.

Comment: Code is actually working. Open DOM inspector and check behaviour of margin

Comment: Ok. When margin-top: -10px; is removed in the OP the position is different. You can easily 'deactivate' in Google developer tools.

Comment: @wazz that's not correct (the part stating that it does nothing). Applying a negative value for `margin-top` on the child [moves the parent element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element) to top. If you want to stay with `margin-top` (instead of `top`) you could e.g. [prevent the](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1939980/3162554) [margin collapsing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3217333/3162554), see this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akw18znv/).

Comment: @all i was just checking in dev tools when all the comments came up. it does change the margin, just can't tell without inspection (or borders or something else).

Comment: Sorry guys... I found my fault... I give the style like this...

.wrapper div {
    margin-top: 0px;
}

It has stronger priority...